# Правильный require_once

Tags: php

Скажите, кто как подключает файлы в php?
Вернее, как правильно подключать? Постоянно возникает ошибка о неправильном пути.

С одной страницы всё работает, с другой нет.

Есть ли оптимальное решение без использование абсолютных путей?

Comment: Если классы подключаете, то правильно было бы использовать [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/ru/), тогда ошибок быть не должно

Comment: Спасибо, методом __autoload я пользуюсь, но как быть с файлами обработчиками, которые подключатся отдельно?

Comment: ну для произвольных файлов если использовать composer, то тоже можно автозагрузчик [использовать](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#files), правда, с условием что эти файлы постоянно подгружаются

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Классическое решение для больших скриптов: в точке входа определяем корневую директорию скрипта. Например так:

PHP >= 5.3

```
define('ROOT_DIR', __DIR__);
```

PHP >= 4.0.2

```
define('ROOT_DIR', dirname(__FILE__));
```

Все версии РНР, но годится только для скрипта в www-директории

```
define('ROOT_DIR', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
```

далее можно во всех компонентах скрипта плясать от ROOT_DIR:

```
require_once ROOT_DIR . '/classes/orders.php';
```

Подобный подход используется во всех популярных CMS, фреймворках и автозагрузчиках.

Comment: Спасибо, хороший ответ.